# ask sugestions for refacting the account table

Tags: mysql, refactoring

The account table has 50 fields, 5 million row and 18G size.
8 fields use the text data type to store the json serialized string.

for example:

```
'purchase_info': '{'first_purchase_time': 1457129480, 'second_purchase_time': 1557129480, 'total_purchase_cost': 5000, 'purchase_counts': 18}'

'recent_game_ids': '['cfef4945-98e1-4b4f-90cc-077cf7d563e6', '0a67c3c4-5103-4440-95ee-1de426e489c9', 'c2d91d8d-fa69-4909-86d6-994259f5577c']'

'friend_ids': '[4354224, 2425355, 3534542]'
```

The former table designer puts all account info into the account table without any join operation, using json serialized string to store multi values. Only the account table, no more other tables.

The project is running well for many years. Is it worth to refacting this text fields. if worth, how to refacting the 'purchase_info' field?

Comment: No. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: some fields's value is over 7495 bytes and the value is changed often. the dao object use 'select * from account' when I just want to get the account name.

Comment: Question will be most likely be voteclosed as way to broad, unclear for missing table structure and or user case or primarily opinion-based

Comment: *"No. If it ain't broke, don't fix it"* Well optimisation isn't fixing it's like putting oli in a engine so it runs smoother more or less @Strawberry  well wanting to do optimisation when no performance issues or knowing your goal is wierd i have to agree on that one.... Topicstarter the only valid reason you might have to refactor those JSON columns is when you need to query and aggregate the data within in the JSON data but keep in mind it most likely also requires alot of application code changes and testing.